# how to flatten multidimensional array containing objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, flatten

I have an multidimensional array with objects in it..How can I flatten it

```
myarr[0] =[{"name":"john","age":"50","location":"san diego"}
           ,{"name":"jane","age":"25","location":"new york"}
           ,{"name":"susane","age":"10","location":"los angeles"}     
               ];
myarr[1] =[{"smoker":"yes","drinker":"no","insured":"no"}
           ,{"smoker":"no","drinker":"no","insured":"yes"}
           ,{"smoker":"no","drinker":"yes","insured":"no"}     
               ];
myarr[1] =[{"status":"married","children":"none"}
           ,{"status":"unmarried","children":"one"}
           ,{"status":"unmarried","children":"two"}     
               ];
```

Comment: flatten means to flatten a multidimensional array --make one dimensional array of it--I mean, sorry for confusion. eg would my array containing all the objects in ascending order.

Comment: Check out `concat` [here](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

First you want a simple helper function to merge two objects:

```
function merge(a, b) {
    a = a || { };
    for(var k in b)
        if(b.hasOwnProperty(k))
            a[k] = b[k];
    return a;
}
```

Then you can just loop through your array of arrays to merge the objects:

```
var flat = [ ];
for(var i = 0; i < myarr.length; ++i)
    for(var j = 0; j < myarr[i].length; ++j)
        flat[j] = merge(flat[j], myarr[i][j]);
```

And then sort it:

```
flat.sort(function(a, b) {
    a = a.location;
    b = b.location;
    if(a < b)
        return -1;
    if(a > b)
        return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Demo (run with your JavaScript console open): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/twpUF/

References:

- [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)
- [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)